# How to add an image as texture on a MeshElement3D?

Tags: helix-3d-toolkit

I've been able to add images as textures on ViewPort2DVisual3D by simply setting the 'Value' field with an Image.

But now I'm trying to use the helix tools and I can't find a way to do the same on a MeshElement3D.

I've been trying with a RectangleVisual3D, but there's nothing such as a 'Visual' field on it.

I bet I should try with the 'Material' field, but all I found is the ImageMaterialExtension object.
But it is not inheriting from Material so I can't give it to my RectangleVisual3D.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, we can just use the Material Helper such as :

```
var mat = MaterialHelper.CreateImageMaterial("img.png", 1, UriKind.Absolute);
```

and add it to the Material of the MeshElement3D